# eval(parse()) for colnames not working

Tags: r, parsing, eval

I am performing:

```
for(i in c(1:4)){
colnames(eval(parse(text = paste0("tabDummy",i)))) <- c("RM", "IVS", "COR", "ANO")
}
```

but R is returning the following error message:

```
Error in colnames(eval(parse(text = paste0("tabDummy", i)))) <- c("RM",  : 
target of assignment expands to non-language object
```

Answer (score 1):

May be this:

`df` is your dataframe

```
y = c("RM", "IVS", "COR", "ANO")
for( x in 1:4 ){
  colnames(df)[ colnames(df) == paste0("tabDummy", x) ] <- y[x]
}
```